# Toshiba satellite l855-10x ram upgrade

Tags: memory, toshiba-laptop

I want to upgrade the 6GB(2+4) of ram in my satellite l855-10x. The plan is to switch the 2GB stick with a 8GB one thus expanding the memory to 12GB (16GB supported).

The remaining 4GB stick is a  Kingston TSB1600D3S1ELD/4GE, DDR3-1600 (800 MHz) 1.5 V    11-11-11-28 @ 800 MHz. I would like to add this: http://www.kingston.com/dataSheets/KVR16S11_8.pdf

As far as i researched these sticks should be compatible, but since the model of my laptop is not available on kingston.com I can't check which ram sticks they recommend. 
Can anybody evaluate my choice in the replacement stick?

Comment: So is the plan 6 GB or 12 GB?  The link you provided does not work by the way.  It is best to provide us all the information on the module in the question itself, so you don't have to worry about, if a link works or not.

Comment: The two modules you are asking about are virtually identical.  I would go as far as saying, they are the same part, what you have currently is just a Toshiba part-number instead of the generic Kingston part-number.

Answer (score 0):

of course compatible ) it's all about brands... but, even there is not significantly differences.

You need to know only this:

http://cdn9.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/windows-7-ram-limits.png